Realtionship between automorphism number of a graph and subgraph count
Suppose we have a simple, undirected, connected graph $G_N$ with $|V(G_N)| = N$ vertices and edge set $E(G_N)$. Graph has a adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}_N = (a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq N}$, where $a_{i,j}\in \{0,1\}$ and $a_{i,i} =0$ since graph is simple and has no self edge, and $\mathbf{A}_N$ is a symmetric matrix because $G_N$ is undirected graph.
Now, Suppose $H$ is a another simple, undirected, connected graph with $m (<)N$ vertices where $V(H) = \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $E(H)\subset V(H)\times V(H)$. Then we want to count the number of such $H$ graph in the bigger graph $G_N$. That number is denoted as $S_{H,N}$ and defined as follows,
\begin{align*}
S_{H,N} = \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_m\leq N} \prod_{(r,s)\in E(H)}a_{i_r,i_s}
\end{align*}
As a example, if $H = K_2$ or an edge, then, $V(K_2) = \{1,2\}$ and $E(H) = \{(1,2)\}$, that is $m=2$ then, number of edges in $G_N$ is
\begin{align}
S_{K_2,N} = \sum_{1\leq i_1< i_2\leq N} a_{i_1,i_2}
\end{align}
Now, similarly we can define another count $S_{H,N}'$ in the following way,
\begin{equation}
S_{H,N}' = \sum_{1\leq i_1\neq i_2\neq \cdots\neq i_m\leq N} \prod_{(r,s)\in E(H)}a_{i_r,i_s},
\end{equation}
and the relation between $S_{H,N}$ and $S_{H,N}'$ is
\begin{align}
S_{H,N} = \frac{1}{|\text{Aut}(H)|}\cdot S_{H,N}'.\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{align}
Here $|\text{Aut}(H)|$ denote the number of automorphism of graph $H$.  An automorphism of a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a permutation $\sigma$ of the vertex set $V$, such that the pair of vertices $(u, v)$ form an edge if and only if the pair $(\sigma(u), \sigma(v))$ also form an edge. Number of such permutation denoted as $|\text{Aut}(G)|$ (defination from wkipedia). As example $|\text{Aut}(K_2)| = 2$.
I didn't find any general, rigorous proof of (1). Any kind of reference regarding the proof (or any nice reference regarding the idea of automorphism group of graph)of $(1)$, or any proof is appreciable.

I think that a way to see $S'_{H,N}$ is just the set of all bijections (i.e., functions $f$ from an arbitrary subset of nodes of size $m$ of the graph $G$),  that ''map'' on $H$. Therefore for each occurrence $H$ in $G$ you will have in $S'_{H,N}$ exactly $|Aut(H)|$ such functions.

Thanks for answer, but how do you proof it formally?

The idea goes as follows consider a pattern $H$ on $m$ vertices. Consider a set of vertices $S = (v_1,\dots,v_m)$ from $G$ such that $e=(k,l)\in E_H \rightarrow (v_k,v_l)\in E(S)$, that is $S$ is an occurrence of $H$ in $G$. Then in $S_{H,N}$ you are considering $S$ only once (as $v_1< v_2< \dots$) while in $S'_{H,N}$ you are considering such set $S$ exactly $|Aut(H)|$ times ($v_1\neq v_2 \neq \dots$), by recalling that $Aut(H)$ is the set of functions that map the pattern $H$ onto itself preserving its structure (i.e., an isomorphism).
